# Is atomic increase and comparsion thread-safe

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

I'm writing multithreaded socket class. BelowBounds() function can be invoked from multiple threads simultaneously, i need to prevent using mutexes. Does this code is thread-safe ?

```
class UDPSocketHT
{
public:
    std::atomic<size_t> m_nSimultaneousRecvCalls;
    std::atomic<size_t> m_nPendingOperations;
    //...
    bool UDPSocketHT::BelowBounds ( )
    {
         return ( !m_nSimultaneousRecvCalls || ( m_nPendingOperations + 1 <= m_nSimultaneousRecvCalls ) ) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Or i must write in this way?

```
bool UDPSocketHT::BelowBounds ( )
{
     size_t x = m_nSimultaneousRecvCalls;
     size_t y = m_nPendingOperations;
     return ( !x || ( y + 1 <= x) ) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but if you have a ternary expression resulting in `true` or `false`, there's really no need for a ternary expression at all. In your last example, you could just as well write `return !x || ( y + 1 <= x);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of your alternatives are unsafe. Each atomic variable *by itself* is atomic, but using two of them in a single statement is not.

You can wrap your check in a mutex or come up with a way to use a single atomic.

**What operations on `std::atomic` are atomic?**

- `operator=` stores a new value atomically
- `load()` or `operator T` (using in an expression) reads the value atomically
- `operator++` increments a value atomically
- `compare_exchange_weak/strong` check and set the value atomically
- [more details](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)

Using two atomics in an expression is not atomic: `a + b` will read `a` atomically, *then* read `b` atomically, but anything can happen in between reading `a` and `b`; by the time you read `b`, `a` can already have another value.